# Directshow with custom resampling transform filter

Tags: c++, audio, directx, directshow

When I insert my custom re-sampling filter into the Filter graph, I set the sample size, as returned by `IMediaSample::GetActualDataLength()`
to the "new" size, depending on whether I am stretching or compressing the original waveform in the time domain.

To the question:
As well as `IMediaSample::SetActualDataLength()`, should I also re-timestamp each sample, or not? This is an audio filter graph only.